# Reliable way to find an intersection between an unfilled StreamGeometry and a RectangleGeometry

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

I have the following unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IntersectionTest()
{
    var lineStreamGeometry = new StreamGeometry { FillRule = FillRule.EvenOdd };
    using (var sgc = lineStreamGeometry.Open())
    {
        sgc.BeginFigure(new Point(), false, false);
        sgc.LineTo(new Point(10, 0), true, true);
        sgc.LineTo(new Point(0, 10), true, true);
    }
    lineStreamGeometry.Freeze();
    var lineGeomtry = new LineGeometry(new Point(), new Point(10,0));
    var rectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Point(-20, -20), new Point(20, 20)));
    var geometryFillContains = rectangleGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(lineGeomtry);
    var streamFillContains = rectangleGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(lineStreamGeometry);
    Assert.AreEqual(geometryFillContains, streamFillContains);
}
```

Both of these lines are inside my `RectangleGeometry`, however the intersection result with the `StreamGeometry` is incorrect. This happens because the `isFilled` parameter of `BeginFigure` is `false`.

I could set `isFilled` to `true` to make the satisfy the unit test, but this gives issues when the `RectangleGeometry` falls within the invisible closing triangle that it causes.

I am looking for a function that works with all kinds of geometries, `FillContainsWithDetail` only works correctly if both geometries are filled/closed polygons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a `Pen` to the `StreamGeometry` solved my issue:

```
var streamFillContains = rectangleGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(lineStreamGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen(null, 0.1)));
```